How to linearise on Lagrangian level?
Consider a Lagrangian density
$$\mathcal{L}(\phi, \nabla \phi) = \frac{1}{2} \, g^{\mu \nu} \, \partial_{\mu} \phi \; \partial_{\nu} \phi + V(\phi) \tag{1}$$
The equation of motion (EOM), i.e. the Euler-Lagrange equation, is
$$\nabla^{\mu} \nabla_{\mu} \phi - \frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi} = 0 \tag{2}$$
Assume now that $\phi = (\phi_0 + \varepsilon)$ and that $\phi_0$ satisfies equation (2). Inserting into said equation (2) and linearising yields
$$\nabla^{\mu} \nabla_{\mu} \varepsilon - \varepsilon \cdot \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial \phi^2} \, \bigg|_{\phi_0} = 0 \tag{3}$$
The corresponding Lagrangian density that yields this EOM in $\varepsilon$ is
$$\tilde{\mathcal{L}}(\varepsilon, \nabla \varepsilon) = \frac{1}{2} \, g^{\mu \nu} \, \partial_{\mu} \varepsilon \; \partial_{\nu} \varepsilon + \varepsilon^2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \, \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial \phi^2} \, \bigg|_{\phi_0}  \tag{4} $$

My question now is, how to obtain the Lagrangian (4) directly from the Lagrangian (1). Since a linear EOM is obtained by a quadratic Lagrangian, linearising (1) does not do the trick. One could "quadratise" (1) to get (4), and assume that the variation of the action associated to (1) vanishes, such that the actual Lagrangian for $\varepsilon$ reads
$$\begin{align} \tilde{\mathcal{L}}(\varepsilon, \nabla \varepsilon) &= \frac{1}{2} \, g^{\mu \nu} \, \partial_{\mu} \phi \; \partial_{\nu} \phi + \sum_{k=0}^{2} ( \phi-\phi_0 )^k \cdot \frac{1}{k!} \frac{\partial^{(k)} V}{\partial \phi^k} \, \bigg|_{\phi_0}  \\
&{} \\
&= \mathcal{L}(\phi_0, \nabla \phi_0) + \frac{1}{2} \, g^{\mu \nu} \,\partial_{\mu} \varepsilon \; \partial_{\nu} \varepsilon + g^{\mu \nu} \, \partial_{\mu} \phi_0 \; \partial_{\nu} \varepsilon + \varepsilon \cdot \frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi} \, \bigg|_{\phi_0} + \varepsilon^2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial \phi^2} \, \bigg|_{\phi_0} \tag{5} \end{align}$$
but then what happens to the term linear in $\varepsilon$? So what actually is "linearising" an equation on the level of the Lagrangian?

UPDATE:
Following the answer of @hft, one may write
$$\begin{align} \tilde{\mathcal{L}}(\varepsilon, \nabla \varepsilon)
&= \mathcal{L}(\phi_0, \nabla \phi_0) + \frac{1}{2} \, g^{\mu \nu} \,\partial_{\mu} \varepsilon \; \partial_{\nu} \varepsilon + \nabla_{\nu} \big( g^{\mu \nu} \, \varepsilon \; \partial_{\mu} \phi_0 \big) - \varepsilon \underbrace{\big( \nabla^{\mu} \nabla_{\mu} \phi_0 + \frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi} \, \bigg|_{\phi_0}\big)}_{= \, 0} + \varepsilon^2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial \phi^2} \, \bigg|_{\phi_0} \\
&{} \\
&= \enspace \mathcal{L}(\phi_0, \nabla \phi_0) + \frac{1}{2} \, g^{\mu \nu} \,\partial_{\mu} \varepsilon \; \partial_{\nu} \varepsilon + \varepsilon^2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial \phi^2} \, \bigg|_{\phi_0} + \nabla_{\mu} \big( \varepsilon \; \nabla^{\mu} \phi_0 \big)\end{align}$$
which is the desired Lagrangian + a divergence term that becomes a surface integral when varying the action. This is a nice explanation. Thank you all for your help.

If you're expanding about $\phi_0$ then $$\left. \frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi} \right|_{\phi_0} = 0$$ and the term vanishes.  Or am I misunderstanding what you're asking?

But why would this derivative at $\phi_0$ vanish? (I've updated the question to add the dependencies for clarity)

That derivative would not generally vanish. OP is not necessarily expanding about the minimum. @MichaelSeifert


Consider a Lagrangian density
$$\mathcal{L}(\phi, \nabla \phi) = \frac{1}{2} \, g^{\mu \nu} \, \partial_{\mu} \phi \; \partial_{\nu} \phi + V(\phi) \tag{1}$$


... Assume now that $\phi = (\phi_0 + \varepsilon)$ and that $\phi_0$ satisfies equation (2). Inserting into said equation (2) and linearising yields
$$\nabla^{\mu} \nabla_{\mu} \varepsilon - \varepsilon \cdot \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial \phi^2} \, \bigg|_{\phi_0} = 0 \tag{3}$$


The corresponding Lagrangian density that yields this EOM in $\varepsilon$ is
$$\tilde{\mathcal{L}}(\varepsilon, \nabla \varepsilon) = \frac{1}{2} \, g^{\mu \nu} \, \partial_{\mu} \varepsilon \; \partial_{\nu} \varepsilon + \varepsilon^2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \, \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial \phi^2} \, \bigg|_{\phi_0}  \tag{4} $$


My question now is, how to obtain the Lagrangian (4) directly from the Lagrangian (1).


... what happens to the term linear in $\varepsilon$?

You have to show that the linear term is a total derivative, and thus doesn't change the equation of motion for epsilon. Remember it is the minimization of the action that generates the equations of motion, and the action is fixed at the boundaries, so a boundary term like a total derivative doesn't change the equation of motion.
From your Eq. (1), we have
$$
L(\phi_0 + \epsilon) = \frac{1}{2}(\partial\phi_0)^2 + \partial \phi_0\cdot\partial\epsilon + \frac{1}{2}(\partial \epsilon)^2
+V(\phi_0)+\epsilon\frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi_0} +\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial \phi_0^2}\epsilon^2+O(\epsilon^3)
$$
$$
=A + B\cdot\partial \epsilon + C\epsilon + \tilde L\;,
$$
where $A$ is completely independent of epsilon, akin to a "constant" in classical mechanics, and clearly does not affect the epsilon equation of motions. And where $B^\mu = \partial^\mu\phi_0$, also independent of epsilon. And where $C=\frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi_0}$, also independent of epsilon. And where $\tilde L$ is your Eq. (4).
But, by the equation of motion for $\phi_0$, we have:
$$
C = \partial\cdot B\;.
$$
So, indeed the linear term is a total derivative:
$$
L = A + \partial\cdot\left(\epsilon B\right) + \tilde L
$$

Thank you a lot for your answer. I have updated the question so that it includes the resolution you provided for the explicit example stated in my question.

Normally you would expand about a fixed point where $V$ is extremum but, if not suppose a point particle in 1d as an example:
$$
L= \tfrac12 m \dot{x}^2 - (V_0+A x + \tfrac12 k x^2)\, .
$$
The EOM for this is
$$
m\ddot{x}=-A-kx=-k \left(\frac{A}{k}+x\right)\, , \tag{1}
$$
with $A\ne 0$. Eq.(1) is a linear ODE so you have linearized the EOM.
Then define $X=x+\frac{A}{k}$ so that
$\ddot{x}=\ddot{X}$ and you have the usual harmonic approximation for $X$.
The factor $\frac{A}{k}$ just adds a constant shift to $x$, and this shift can usually be ignored unless $V’’=0$.  You should be able to easily convert this argument to fields.

The underlying motivation for linearizing an equation of motion is that you are looking for small deviations to a known solution of the full equations of motion. The approximation is valid so long as these deviations remain small. If the deviations do not remain small, then the approximation breaks down.
A linear term in the Lagrangian corresponds to a constant term in the equations of motion. From your intuition from classical particle mechanics, you know this constant term would correspond to a constant force, leading to a constant acceleration. A perturbation experiencing a constant acceleration will inevitably become large, meaning that the expansion is breaking down.
The underlying reason you are finding this instability is that you are not expanding around a legitimate solution of the full equations of motion. If you were, the linear term would vanish. This follows because the principle of least action states that all first order variations of the action vanish when the Euler-Lagrange equations are satisfied.
In the special case of a potential, then a constant value of the field sitting at the minimum of the potential is a valid solution of the equations of motion, but a constant value of the field sitting at some random spot on the potential that has a non-vanishing derivative is not a solution -- the equation of motion will make the field roll down the potential.

Assume $\phi_0$ is a time-independent solution to the EOM derived from the Lagrangian in equation (1). In that case, one would not have
$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi} , \bigg|_{\phi_0} = 0$$
but rather
$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial \phi} , \bigg|{\phi_0} = \nabla^{\mu} \nabla{\mu} \phi_0$$
with only the time-derivatives dropping. In that case the field $\phi_0$ does not (!) mark the minimum of $V$. How is this consistent with what you said? And what do you mean by all first order variations vanish?

@Octavius When I said "constant", I meant "constant in space and time", sorry if that wasn't clear. By "all first order variations vanish", I mean in a calculus of variations sense. To derive the Euler Lagrange equations, you take $x(t)$ and perturb it by a variation $x(t)+\epsilon(t)$. Then the requirement that the variation in the action $S$ vanishes to linear order in epsilon, $S[x+\epsilon]-S[x] = O(\epsilon^2)$, gives you the Euler Lagrange equations. So if the background $\phi_0$ obeys the EL equations, then the first order term in an expansion of $S$ will vanish. If $\phi_0$ (...)

(...) does not obey the EL equations, then you are not perturbing about a solution of the equations of motion, and so the perturbative expansion is not stable.
